# How to reformat old code into new one with table prefixes?

Tags: sql-server

we have a bunch of stored procedures which we would like to have cleary and unified formatted, including a table prefixes.

E.g.:
We have:

```
SELECT [SalesRegionId], [SalesRegionName]
FROM dim.[SalesRegion]
WHERE [SalesRegionId] BETWEEN 1 AND 7
```

and we want:

```
SELECT 
        [sr].[SalesRegionId]
       ,[sr].[SalesRegionName]
FROM 
       dim.[SalesRegion] sr
WHERE 
      [sr].[SalesRegionId] BETWEEN 1 AND 7
```

Is there a way how to automate the process?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot `[dim].`

Comment: If there is a way to automate this it's going to be some custom scripting to interrogate your SQL object code, generate dynamic SQL to modify those objects, and then execute the changes.  It doesn't sound trivial to me and definitely feels like there's a high potential for introducing bugs.  Not only that, but this is throwaway code once it's completed.  Why not modify these by hand as you come across them?

Comment: Automated introduction of prefixes doesn't sound good as soon as you consider that a table may appear multiple times in a `FROM` clause. At that point, you generally need a human being to apply appropriate names to distinguish each individual usage to tell you *why*.

Comment: Why would you want to put commas at the beginning of a line, with no space between the comma and the next word?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have often seen people suggest this "so that you can comment out any one column easily" when these people don't see that when they say "any one column" they're ignoring the first column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . I stand by the observation that I'm a human being who reads Latin-based alphabets where the comma is used as punctuation and never used in this fashion.  It is even rather contradictory to the original designers of SQL who wanted a language suitable for less technical people (I'm not saying they succeeded, only that they tried).

Answer (score -1):

I found what appears to be this exact question on MSDN [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a9d900fd-b81f-42be-bde0-1f595c888d94/prefix-alias-for-columns-in-select-query?forum=transactsql). The basics of it are as follows:

> 1. Position to AdventureWorks2008 or your database  in SSMS Query Editor
> 2. Enter the following or your query:
>
> select * from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh inner join
>   Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
>
> 3. Select Design Query in Query drop-down menu
> 4. You will see  the * replaced by columns with aliases.
> 5. Press OK at the bottom

Using this method, you can change your query to use `*`, and then just clean up the field list, or you should be able to select the actual columns you want from the query designer.